# GIS - How to dissolve un connected polygons

Tags: geometry, arcgis, qgis, shapely, arcpy

How can I dissolve polygons that are close to each other but not touching, using arcgis or qgis?

I have original output:
[original output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sIUS.png)

I want it to dissolve in a generalized way and become like this but not rounded:
[buffered and re-buffered output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyUti.png)

To achieve my goal, I have buffered the output 3 m (with dissolve) and then buffered -3 m try to preserve original extent. But I get some sort of distorted shape. Almost every corner of dissolved polygon is rounded.

Comparison:
[comparison(green:original, blue:buffered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdPe5.png)

I tried aggregate polygons but it took too long and it didn't give me what I want.

Answer (score 2):

How about using [alpha shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape), does that look like a result you are looking for?

[image: result]

You did not ask for a solution in python but since you did tag shapely here is a solution using python (geom here is shapely object collection).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

im = plt.imread('input.png')

array = im[:, :, 1] < 0.8

plt.imshow(array)

import alphashape
points = np.array(np.where(array)).T
geom = alphashape.alphashape(points, 0.1)

# For visualization
with open('test.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(geom._repr_svg_())
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('test.svg')
```

Answer (score 0):

Arcgis solutions.
Select All and Merge make dissolved polygon of all previous individual polygons.

```
selected_polys = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(in_laye)
arcpy.management.Merge([selected_polys], output_layer)
```

Or selecting all in table and using merge editing tool, or a few options with dissolve from below link.

https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/merging-features-in-feature-class-with-arcpy/td-p/466856

Answer (score 0):

If you can run standalone python scripts you could try the (new) [dissolve_within_distance](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/geofileops.dissolve_within_distance.html#geofileops.dissolve_within_distance) feature of [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io).

It offers a basic subset of features of "aggregate polygons", but gives slightly different results in some cases, so maybe it is a better match to what you are looking for. It is also a lot faster for large datasets.

```
import logging
import geofileops as gfo

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Init logging so progress printed by gfo is shown
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    input_path = "/path/you/like/zones.gpkg"
    output_path = "/path/you/like/zones_dissolved.gpkg"
    gfo.dissolve_within_distance(
        input_path=input_path, output_path=output_path, distance=6
    )
```

Disclaimer: I am the developer of [geofileops](https://geofileops.readthedocs.io).